# How to insert two arralist into SQLite at sametime?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I  created a database for my application. I am trying to insert 3 values. But my problem is when trying to insert second values,they go to first column. And this value from user"s phone numbers( so from content provider). When I trying to launch my code all column is set up at first column except or a column. I want to set theses values to 3 different column. It's showing me 10 result but I selected 5 name. I want to show 5 results. Other 5 results go to column 2. I am using custom listview at second activity. On the other hand, they may loaded at first column but I can not see my number values I am beginner at database.

I want to just like :

```
ID name    number  oran 
1  Ahmet   5555    50
2  Mehmet  6666    50
3  Veli    3333    50
4  Can     2222    50
5  Zehra   11111   50 
etc.
```

My databaseHelper :

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "name";
    private static final String COL3 = "number";
    private static final String COL4 = "oran";



     public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
        }
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  COL2 + " TEXT,"+
                     COL3 + " TEXT,"+  COL4 + " TEXT)";
            db.execSQL(createTable);
        }
      // COL2 +" TEXT)0" col3 yerine 2 koyulması gerekiyor.
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
            db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public boolean addData(String item , String number   ) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(COL2, item );
    contentValues.put(COL3 , number);
    contentValues.put(COL4, "50");


            Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

            long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

            //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
            if (result == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

When user clicked saving data button :

```
 for (String newEntry: selectedlist)
                                AddData(newEntry,null);    {

                            }
                            for (String number : selectedlistarama)
                                AddData(null , number);    {

                            }
```

Adding values :

```
 private void AddData(String newEntry ,String number) {

        boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData(newEntry ,number);
        if (insertData) {
            Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
            sayı = data.getCount();
            //   toastMessage("Data Successfully Inserted!");
            Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(sayı), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            toastMessage("Something went wrong");
        }

    }
```

Getting values from database  at Second Activity:

```
 while(data.moveToNext()) {

            listData.add(data.getString(1));

            listDatanumber.add(data.getString(2));

           listDataoran.add(data.getString(3));
    }
```

My Custom_adapter :

```
namesbox.setText(listData.get(position));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the for loop? Also check if it is well written, and you can correct the indetation on the way.

Comment: I am trying to record all arraylist to DataBase.If you are asking me Why are you put null ?Because My databasehelper could not applied.I want to set   
selectedlist to column 1 and selectedlistarama to column 2.

Comment: See my answer if I understood correctly your poblem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

`selectedlist` is the ArrayList of `String` for COL_2 (name).

`selectedlistarama` is the ArrayList of `String` for COL_3 (number).

Note: if for number you really want to keep numbers use `ArrayList<Integer>` and store int values.

I also assume that there is the same number of items in both lists so the first item of  selectedlist corrsponds with the first item of selectedlistarama and so on.

Then, to call `addData(String String)` you would do like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<selectedlist.size(); i++){
    String name = selectedlist.get(i);
    String number = selectedlistarama.get(i);
    addData(name, number);
}
```

Comment: Yes your answer is corrent.Thanks for helping.Also I want to improve my question for other users.What do you mean check your written ?Do you mean your english grammer is bad or your code is bad.What is your recommend ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was refering to the code. I think the for look has a { opened on wrong line.

Comment: No problem.Good coding.